# centos7 compile openjdk8 run get_source.sh something wrong

Tags: compilation, centos7

when I run `get_source.sh` something wrong

> ./get_source.sh  ERROR: Need initial repository to use this script

this is history:

```
 1. hg init jdk8
 2. hg -r pull 20 http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8
 3. hg pull -r 500 http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8
 4. hg pull -r 941 http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8
 5. chmod +x get_source.sh
 6. ./get_source.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. hg init jdk
2. cd jdk/.hg
3. eamcs -nw hgrc

> ## example repository config (see "hg help config" for more info)
>
> [paths]
>   default = http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/
>
> ## path aliases to other clones of this repo in URLs or filesystem paths
>
> ## (see "hg help config.paths" for more info)
>
> #
>
> ## default-push = ssh://jdoe@example.net/hg/jdoes-fork
>
> ## my-fork      = ssh://jdoe@example.net/hg/jdoes-fork
>
> ## my-clone     = /home/jdoe/jdoes-clone
>
> [ui]
>
> ## name and email (local to this repository, optional), e.g.
>
> ## username = Jane Doe

end

Comment: #example repository config (see "hg help config" for more info)

#[paths] 

default = http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u60/
#path aliases to other clones of this repo in URLs or filesystem paths
#(see "hg help config.paths" for more info)

#default-push = ssh://jdoe@example.net/hg/jdoes-fork
#my-fork = ssh://jdoe@example.net/hg/jdoes-fork
#my-clone = /home/jdoe/jdoes-clone

#[ui]
#name and email (local to this repository, optional), e.g.
#username = Jane Doe

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the following instructions which i took from [readme](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/file/866ed739fa56/README) file for downloading source code. They worked for me.

```
hg clone http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8 YourOpenJDK 
cd YourOpenJDK 
bash ./get_source.sh
```